# Behat : Cant activate the mink extension in feature context

Tags: behat

I try to create a context with Behat but I have always this error :
"Mink instance has not been set on Mink context class. Have you enabled the Mink Extension? (RuntimeException)"

I tried a lot of things to activate it, I change my behat.yml, I add to composer
but nothing changing.
I tried all the solutions i saw on the web, now i'm lost...
This is the behat.yml

```
   default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
        sessions:
                  goutte:
                      goutte: ~
                  selenium2:
                      selenium2: ~
                  symfony2:
                      symfony2: ~
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext
                - Mink\MinkExtension\Context\DrupalContext
                - Mink\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
```

And my context

```
    use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterStepScope;
use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Mink\Mink;


/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if `FeatureContext` extends `MinkContext` or another class that extends `MinkContext`, then you need to add to the contexts in `behat.yml` just the `FeatureContext`.

Also in your feature add `@api` tag to use the `goutte` driver or add `@javascript` to use `selenium2` driver.